# mat-dialog pop up navigates page back to the default route

Tags: angular, dialog, angular-material

I am trying to pop up a mat dialog box on my current page but when I click the button to pop up the dialog, the dialog comes up but then navigates me to my default route instead of staying on same page.

This is my `router` module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'main-nav', component: MainNavComponent, children: [
    { path: 'create-service', component: CreateServiceComponent },
    { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
    { path: 'designations', component: DesignationsComponent, children: [
      { path: 'dialog', component: AddDesignationsComponent }
    ] },
  ] }
];
```

I am trying to pop up the `AddDesignationsComponent` under `DesignationsComponent` with a button click but instead it pops up and navigates the page to the `HomeComponent`. I guess my error is coming from my routing pattern but I can't seem to figure it out.

Where could I be going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case. Can you share a Sample StackBlitz replicating this issue?

Comment: How are you opening dialog? AddDesignationsComponent  and DesignationsComponent , please show their relevant code of .ts and .html .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, my mistake. Was using a click event and routerLink together.

[mat-dialog pop up and navigates page back to the app's default route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57028378/mat-dialog-pop-up-and-navigates-page-back-to-the-apps-default-route)

Answer (score 0):

The order of route configuration matters. The router accepts the first route that matches a navigation request path. Make sure the empty path route (HomeComponent) is listed last.

From the docs:

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes.

Comment: Thanks Ritchie. I already tried it out but it still gives me the same result. I even tried giving the HomeComponent a path, this time, the page now navigates to an empty page though the dialog still shows up on both cases