# mat-dialog pop up and navigates page back to the app's default route

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to pop up a mat dialog box on my current page but when I click the button to pop up the dialog, the dialog comes up but then navigates to default route instead of staying on same page. The dialog box is still shown.

This is my router module:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: 'main-nav', component: MainNavComponent, children: [
      { path: 'create-service', component: CreateServiceComponent },
      { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
      { path: 'designations', component: DesignationsComponent, children: [
          { path: 'dialog', component: AddDesignationsComponent }
        ]
      },
    ] 
  }
];
```

I am trying to pop up the `AddDesignationsComponent` under `DesignationsComponent` as a mat-dialog box on button click but instead it pops up and navigates the page to the `HomeComponent`. I guess my error is coming from my routing pattern but I can't seem to figure it out.

My DesignationsComponent ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { AddDesignationsComponent } from '../add-designations/add-designations.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-designations',
  templateUrl: './designations.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./designations.component.css']
})
export class DesignationsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }

  openDialog() {
    this.dialog.open(AddDesignationsComponent);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

DesignationsComponent Html:

```
<button mat-raised-button routerLink='' id="design-btn" (click)='openDialog()'>
   <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Add a new Designation
</button>
```

I am loading the `DesignationComponent` under the `MainNavComponent` as a child with the `router-outlet`. I noticed the code works correctly when i change from `router-outlet` to `app-designations` in my `app.component.html` but fails again when i start using `router-outlet`. I already tried giving the `HomeComponent` a path, but this time, an empty page is shown though the dialog box still shows up
Where could I be going wrong. Thanks.

Comment: can you show the content of `designations.component.html` please?

Comment: @ysf just updated the question. designations.component.html just contains a button to call the dialog function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `routerLink` directive and `(click)` event together. that causes the problematic behavior. `(click)='openDialog()'` opens the dialog and `routerLink=''` causes your app to route to empty route.

just remove `routerLink=''` and you'll be fine.

```html
<button mat-raised-button id="design-btn" (click)='openDialog()'>
   <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>Add a new Designation
</button>
```

Comment: thanks @ysf. It worked. I did not even notice that.